# Update the database when timer counts down to zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a countdown timer which uses ajax calls to update itself. Something like

```
<div class="timer5">--:--:--</div>
```

I want to call a PHP function (only once) using jQuery which will update the database once the timer goes to 00:00:00.

The thing is, the timer can be increased at any time (it's an auction) so I can't just run a script after X time that will update the DB. I have to call the script when the timer really reaches zero.

How can this be done? Is there a some sort of an event in jQuery for that?

Comment: Use Javascript for timer, and call an Ajax function when the timer ends and remove the function when it ends execution.

Comment: store this timer value in a js variable as well and settimeout to it, update that variable on every ajax update. call the php function on timeout.

Comment: This needs to be controlled on the server.  What if two people have the page open at the same time?

Comment: I forgot to mention I have about 20 of these timers. So I think one timer variable won't do the job...

Comment: what plugin your using for timer.How could you get the end time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience [jquery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#onExpiry) is good for these things.Using this plugin you can easily do this.

```
var auction_id = array('1','2','3','4','5') // auction ids in array

jQuery(auction_id).each(function(key, val){

    jQuery('.countbox-'+val).countdown({
    //other options ref in plugin link
    onExpiry: function(){ 

     sold(val); // passing argument 

    //ajax call goes here to update db

    }
    }); 
}
```

To update your clock, I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499232/penny-auction-website-architecture). The second part of the answer will be help full for you.

if you want to create multiple auction clock in page.you need to collect all auction ids
in array.then you can create clock for each of auction.

Comment: But you can't pass arguments to the onExpiry(). I think atleast. And I need to pass an argument. Thats why I think using this plugin wouldn't help me much.

Answer (score 1):

If it's done using AJAX you already get a call to your server, updating the timer and knowing how much time is left. Do the database update there.